# How can i isolate a range object?

Tags: google-apps-script

Two two questions in fact :
I try to understand the Range object *and* how to be "out of spreradsheet.app" in my script calculations.
here is an example : i try to get that "A1" range object from my spreadsheet **once**, before the first 'alert' and not a permanent object.
How to do ?

```
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").setBackground("blue")
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").setValue("blabla")
  const toto = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1")

var pos = toto.getA1Notation()
var col = toto.getBackground()

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("you have pos : "+pos+" and col "+col)
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").setBackground("orange")

  var col = toto.getBackground()
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("you have pos : "+pos+" and col "+col)
}
```

Even if i stated toto as a const, the second col change to "orange", i dont want that !

Edit :
Following comments, the range object is more a 'location' that can follow and change **in** the variable (even the constant) built with it, than an 'object' i can use to create a variable.
So, how can i cut the link between this range and the variable ?     thank you ^^

Comment: I don't know what your trying to accomplish.  Seems kind of useless to me.

Comment: Cooper again ! ^^ i try to get the data ONCE from the spreadsheet, make change          'in-script' then apply it to the spreadsheet. For that i try to fully understand the Range object (cant find detailed documentation). And specially here i cant stand my const changing...

Comment: The range does not return values is just a location or an array of locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Google Apps Script's documentation on the Range Class:

> A range can be a single cell in a sheet or a group of adjacent cells in a sheet.

You *cannot* separate the range from the spreadsheet as the range is an object specific to the Range Class which is a child class of SpreadsheetApp.

So just because you are assigning it to a `const`, it doesn't mean that it won't change; this is due to the fact that the range is not a *value* and `const` is used to define a constant reference to a value.

If you don't want to change the color of the cell which belongs to the `A1` cell, simply remove this line of code:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a1").setBackground("orange");
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range);
- [JavaScript const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).